# special character parsing in handlebar using triple braces

Tags: handlebars.js

I have json in which for a key there is HTML code. In that html code there is special char ($ - dollar).

```
{
   "output": {"agreementText": "test data",
    "edgeTerms": [
      {
        "edgeDeviceName": "Apple&reg; iPhone&reg; 6 Plus 16GB in Gold",
        "deviceLabel": null,
        "edgeTermsAndCondition": "<h3>RETAIL INSTALLMENT SALE AGREEMENT / RETAIL INSTALLMENT OBLIGATION &#8212; SUBJECT TO STATE REGULATION</h3> <p>Price $59 and discount $2</p> "
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

When i am trying to paint json data in html using triple curly braces for HTML parsing like

```
 {{{edgeTermsAndCondition}}}
```

page goes blank but when i using double curly brace it is painting fine but HTML tags as string, which i don't want.

Please help.

Comment: It just works fine for me. Maybe there is an error somewhere else

Comment: using triple braces u are getting parsed html in ur UI?

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/op6d4tnp/